# Cut down this huge string (php)

Tags: php, string, query-string

I have the following string and need to cut it into pieces. But how to do this correct?

The string: `$sting = 0nl10000143947019,23000143947456,....,10450143947022`

`...` means that more nrs can be in here

Now I want to cut down this string in the following parts:

`$first` contains the first nr or letter in the string. So in this case it should be: `0`

`$second` contains the second and third nrs or letters in the string. So in this case it should be: `nl`

`$third` contains EVERYTHING after the third nr or letter in the string. So in this case it should be: `10000143947019,23000143947456,....,10450143947022`

`$fourth` contains EVERYTHING after the last `,` in the string. Note the this nr can be bigger or smaller than in this excample. So in this case it should be: `10450143947022`

Hope this is possible!

Kind regards

Comment: what is the intended output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$first = substr($sting,0,1);
$second = substr($sting,1,2);
$third = substr($sting,3);
$fourth = end(explode(',',$sting));
```

Comment: Going for this one, it's simple and works like a charm. Thanks all!

Answer (score 3):

Regex should do it, here's something to get you started

```
preg_match("/^(\d+)([a-z]+)(.*?,([^,]*))$/i", $string, $m);

print_r($m);
```

See here:

http://ideone.com/Xk1oV

Answer (score 3):

With a simple regexp

```
([0-9A-Za-z]{1})([0-9A-Za-z]{2})(.*)\,([^\,]+)$
```

Should work. In PHP this would work like

```
$string = "0nl10000143947019,23000143947456,23000143947456,10450143947022";
preg_match("@([0-9A-Za-z]{1})([0-9A-Za-z]{2})(.*)\,([^\,]+)$@i", $string, $matches);
// map $matches to the right variables. But you can do that yourself :-)
```